# sum query in mysql with subtraction and joins

Tags: mysql

So I have two tables: `supply_inventory_list` and `supply_employee_list`

This is the `supply_inventory_list`

```
supply_id  quantity  unit    item_name         supply_description      date_received         
---------  --------  ------  ----------------  ----------------------  -------------  
        1         5  REAM    LEGAL BOND PAPER  CANON LEGAL BOND PAPER  2019-08-28
        2         5  REAM    LEGAL BOND PAPER  HP LEGAL BOND PAPER     2019-08-30
        3         5  REAM    A4 BOND PAPER     CANON A4 BOND PAPER     2019-08-28
        4         5  REAM    A4 BOND PAPER     HP A4 BOND PAPER        2019-08-30
        5         3  PIECE   PENCIL            FABER-CASTELL GRIP 2011 2019-08-26
```

And this is the `supply_employee_list`

```
emp_supply_id  supply_id  deployed_quantity  employee_name  date_deployed       
-------------  ---------  -----------------  -------------  -------------------  
            1          2                  2  ALEX WILLARD   2019-08-28 08:16:00 
            2          1                  3  MARK JACOBS    2019-08-28 08:18:00 
            3          3                  1  DAVE SALES     2019-08-28 08:18:00 
            4          4                  1  JOE COLLINS    2019-08-28 08:31:00
```

Now I want to sum the `quantity` in `supply_inventory_list` group by `item_name` and deducted by the `deployed_quantity` in `supply_employee_list`. So the total quantity should be the sum of quantity in supply_inventory_list minus the deducted_quantity in supply_employee_list. I tried this query but the result is wrong.

```
SELECT 
  SIL.supply_id,
  SUM(SIL.quantity) - IFNULL(SEL.deployed_quantity, 0) AS 'AVAILABLE QUANTITY',
  SIL.unit,
  SIL.item_name ,
  SIL.supply_description,
  IFNULL(SEL.deployed_quantity, 0) AS 'deployed_quantity' 
FROM
  supply_inventory_list SIL 
  LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT 
      supply_id,
      SUM(deployed_quantity) deployed_quantity 
    FROM
      supply_employee_list 
    GROUP BY supply_id) SEL 
    ON SEL.`supply_id` = SIL.`supply_id` 
GROUP BY SIL.item_name 
ORDER BY SIL.item_name ASC
```

And this is the result and it is wrong:

```
supply_id  AVAILABLE QUANTITY  unit    item_name         supply_description      deployed_quantity  
---------  ------------------  ------  ----------------  ----------------------  -------------------
        3  9                   REAM    A4 BOND PAPER     CANON A4 BOND PAPER     1                  
        1  7                   REAM    LEGAL BOND PAPER  CANON LEGAL BOND PAPER  3  
        5  3                   PIECE   PENCIL            FABER-CASTELL GRIP 2011 0
```

The result should be like this:

```
supply_id  AVAILABLE QUANTITY  unit    item_name         supply_description      deployed_quantity  
---------  ------------------  ------  ----------------  ----------------------  -------------------
        3  8                   REAM    A4 BOND PAPER     CANON A4 BOND PAPER     2                  
        1  5                   REAM    LEGAL BOND PAPER  CANON LEGAL BOND PAPER  5         
        5  3                   PIECE   PENCIL            FABER-CASTELL GRIP 2011 0
```

The available quantity for A4 BOND PAPER is 8 because the total quantity is 10 and there are two employees who deployed 1 REAM A4 BOND PAPER each. And for LEGAL BOND PAPER is 5 because one employee deployed 2 and the other is 3. How to achieve this?

Comment: A4 BOND PAPER's quantity is 10 based on addition of supply_id 3 & 4. There were 2 quantity deployed for that item. Why does your result show 1?

Comment: typo error @zedfoxus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check whether this meets your requirement.

```
SELECT min(supply_id), sum(A.aq), min(A.unit), A.item_name, MIN(A.supply_description) as supply_description
, MAX(A.deployed_quantity) as deployed_quantity from
(SELECT 
  SIL.quantity - COALESCE(SEL.deployed_quantity, 0) AS aq,
  SIL.unit,
  SIL.item_name ,
  SIL.supply_description,
  SIL.supply_id,
  SEL.deployed_quantity
FROM
  supply_inventory_list SIL 
  LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT 
      supply_id,
      SUM(deployed_quantity) deployed_quantity 
    FROM
      supply_employee_list 
    GROUP BY supply_id) SEL 
    ON SEL.supply_id = SIL.supply_id) as A
GROUP BY A.item_name
ORDER BY A.item_name ASC ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this query:

```
select
    x.supply_id,
    main.available_quantity,
    x.unit,
    x.item_name,
    x.supply_description,
    main.deployed
from supply_inventory_list x
inner join (

    select
        a.item_name, 
        min(a.supply_id) as min_supply_id,
        sum(a.quantity-b.deployed_quantity) as available_quantity,
        sum(b.deployed_quantity) as deployed
    from supply_inventory_list a
    left join supply_employee_list b on a.supply_id = b.supply_id
    group by a.item_name

) main on
    x.item_name = main.item_name
    and x.supply_id = main.min_supply_id;
```

The result is:

```
supply_id available_quantity unit item_name        supply_description   deployed
--------- ------------------ ---- ---------------- -------------------- --------
1           5                REAM LEGAL BOND PAPER CANON LEGAL BOND PAPER     5
3           8                REAM A4 BOND PAPER    CANON A4 BOND PAPER        2
```

Working example is here: https://rextester.com/WOLO73152

If you wanted `deployed` field to show 1 for A4 BOND PAPER and 3 for LEGAL BOND PAPER, change `sum(b.deployed_quantity) as deployed` to `max(b.deployed_quantity) as deployed`.

## EDIT

Your query would change a bit to this:

```
select
    x.supply_id,
    main.available_quantity,
    x.unit,
    x.item_name,
    x.supply_description,
    main.deployed
from supply_inventory_list x
inner join (
    select
        a.item_name, 
        min(a.supply_id) as min_supply_id,
        sum(a.quantity-coalesce(b.deployed_quantity,0)) as available_quantity,
        sum(coalesce(b.deployed_quantity,0)) as deployed
    from supply_inventory_list a
    left join supply_employee_list b on a.supply_id = b.supply_id
    group by a.item_name
) main on
    x.item_name = main.item_name
    and x.supply_id = main.min_supply_id;
```

Result:

```
supply_id avail.. unit  item_name        supply_description      deployed
--------- ------- ----- ---------------- ----------------------- --------
1         5       REAM  LEGAL BOND PAPER CANON LEGAL BOND PAPER     5
3         8       REAM  A4 BOND PAPER    CANON A4 BOND PAPER        2
5         3       PIECE PENCIL           FABER-CASTELL GRIP 2011    0
```

See example here: https://rextester.com/UJEJ75604

Comment: this should not be `inner join` because there are items in `supply_inventory_list` that are not yet deployed. Like they don't have data in `supply_employee_list`.

Comment: @Rak, answer has been updated to reflect your needs. If this suits your needs, please be sure to mark one of the answers as accepted to put a closure to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think supply_id and supply_description column in your desired output is incorrect. You can try this piece of code to find if it can help you.

```
select 
    Item_Name, 
    sum((sil.Quantity-sel.Deployed_Quantity)) as AvailableQuantity, Unit
    from Supply_Inventory_List as SIL
    Inner Join Supply_Employee_List as SEL
    on SIl.Supply_Id = SEL.Supply_Id
    group by sil.Item_Name, sil.Unit
```